# What command to get nodejs's output with putty?

Tags: linux, node.js

Good day,

I am connecting to my server via putty (and xming) ,
Is there a teminal command for accessing to the node process's output that is currently running?

What I am currently doing is killing the process and launching it again to get the output, but it is not very good because it reinitiate everything

I also want to be abble to enter some commands because there is a readline

Thanks you

Comment: How to you put the process in the background (nohup, forever, upstart)?

Comment: I don't put it in the background, I just run it directly from the server with a keyboard and a screen. But I want to access it remotely as well

Answer (score 0):

you can log the output to file by using command

```
node server.js > server.log
```

and than can access this log file using putty

Comment: But there is like 1 new line every seconds. Moreover I also want to enter some commands via readline